# Repetir el fondo al generar un html a pdf en nodejs

Tags: html, css, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando crear un servidor que retorna un pdf de prueba

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');

app.use(express.static('public'));

var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});

app.listen(3000)
```

este es el código con el cual creo el pdf en el servidor de nodejs
el detalle es que al generar el pdf solo me manda el fondo en la primera pagina del cuerpo.

[image: PDF generado]

Este es el resultado

este es el html que utilizo para generar el pdf de pruba

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://localhost:3000/img/fondo.png);width: 816px;height: 1056px;border:1px solid red">
        <table style="color: black">
            <th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hola</td>
                </tr>
            </th>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>hola</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>hola</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

ya intente utilizando la propiedad repeat en y, y aun así no funciona

Alguien podría ayudarme

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pega el código como texto en lugar de usar capturas de pantalla.

Comment: Listo ya esta editado, tuve que eliminar muchos tr, pero en si ese es el codigo de la plantilla en html @DjCrazy

Comment: Has probado utilizando `background-repeat` ??, trata de agregar esta propiedad a tu style`background-repeat: repeat-x;`

Comment: width: 100%;height: 100%; as probado?

Comment: Perdoname, la propiedad para que lo haga horizontal es `repeat-y` y no `repeat-x`

Comment: Si ya intente agregando esta propiedad y aun así el fondo solo aparece en la primera pagina